# How to do complex conditional processing in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do some post-processing on Doxygen XML output and have trouble to achieve what I need.

I'm modifying some existing XSLT and don't have too much experience with  XML/XSL, so pardon me if I speak C and not XML :)

## input.xml

Ingress Handling

```
<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="about" kind="page">
    <title>About This Document</title>
</compounddef> 

<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="ih" kind="page">
   <title>Ingress Handling</title>
</compounddef>
```

## expected_output.xml

```
  <compounddef id="about" kind="page">
    <title>About This Document</title>
  </compounddef>

  <sect1 id="ih">
    <title>About This Document</title>
  </sect1>
```

So basically I need to change the level of indentation for the page if it happens to be an inner page. I.e. all pages need to become sect1 all sect1 -> sect2 etc... 
Currently, I'm trying to get the first level, and I hope I will be able to extrapolate later on for rest (I think if I get it to the first level I can call apply-templates with parameters for rest of processing).

I do know how to match all pages :

## transform.xslt

```
<xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page']">
   <compounddef id="{@id}" kind="{@kind}">
         <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
    </compounddef>
</xsl:template>
```

but  I need to add some `if` statement that will compare the current element to a group of other elements. Speaking C here:

I need to create a list of all inner pages and compare each element in the template above to this list and if match output `sect1` if not `compounddef`.

Sounds very simple in C, but  I have no idea how to achieve this with XSLT.
 Solution for XSLT 1.0 is preferable, I'm working with `xsltpoc` by default, but can consider over options as well.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Ilya.

**Update**

Thanks, this is working. Working with XSLT 1.0 as well. But still need some help:

## input.xml

```
<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="about" kind="page">
    <title>About This Document</title>
    <innerpage refid="ih">Ingress Handling</innerpage>
</compounddef> 

<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="ih" kind="page">
   <title>Ingress Handling</title>
</compounddef>
```

## transform.xslt

```
    <xsl:key name="inner-page-ref" match="compounddef[@kind='page']/innerpage" use="@refid"/>

    <!-- remove unmatched -->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

   <xsl:template match="/doxygen">
        <doxygen version="{@version}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "compounddef[@kind='page' and not(key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"/> 
        </doxygen>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef/innerpage" mode="list"> 
        <innerpage> 
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </innerpage>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef/innerpage" mode="body"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "/doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page' and key('inner-page-ref', @id)]"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page'and not(key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"> 
            <compounddef id="{@id}" kind="{@kind}">
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="list" select = "innerpage"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="body" select = "innerpage"/>
           </compounddef>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page'and (key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"> 

            <xsl:message> innerpage <xsl:value-of select ="@refid"/> </xsl:message>
            <sect1 id="{@id}" kind="{@kind}">
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
            </sect1>
    </xsl:template>
```

## output.xml

```
 <compounddef id="packet_process" kind="page">
    <title>Packet Processing</title>
    <innerpage>Ingress Handling</innerpage>
    <innerpage>Packet Modification</innerpage>
    <innerpage>Packet Forwarding</innerpage>
    <innerpage>Egress Handling</innerpage>
    <innerpage>
      <sect1 id="ingress_handling" kind="page">
        <title>Ingress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="pm" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Modification</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_forward" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Forwarding</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_egress" kind="page">
        <title>Egress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
    </innerpage>
    <innerpage>
      <sect1 id="ingress_handling" kind="page">
        <title>Ingress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="pm" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Modification</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_forward" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Forwarding</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_egress" kind="page">
        <title>Egress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
    </innerpage>
    <innerpage>
      <sect1 id="ingress_handling" kind="page">
        <title>Ingress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="pm" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Modification</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_forward" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Forwarding</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_egress" kind="page">
        <title>Egress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
    </innerpage>
    <innerpage>
      <sect1 id="ingress_handling" kind="page">
        <title>Ingress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="pm" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Modification</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_forward" kind="page">
        <title>Packet Forwarding</title>
      </sect1>
      <sect1 id="packet_egress" kind="page">
        <title>Egress Handling</title>
      </sect1>
    </innerpage>
  </compounddef>
```

This is almost good, i.e. I generate almost correct output. It's worked for a single instance, but in case I have many inner pages in different pages it does not work.

I.e. I need to create groups of inner pages for each page that has it and process it.

Looking for a solution will update once found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a key (as a top-level child of `xsl:transform` or `xsl:stylesheet`):

```
<xsl:key name="inner-page-ref" match="innerpage" use="@refid"/>
```

then write a template

```
<xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page' and key('inner-page-ref', @id)]">
   <sect1 id="{@id}">
         <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
    </sect1>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope that approach is possible in XSLT 1, there is some restriction on keys in match patterns.

Comment: The `xsl:key` declaration indexes all `innerpage` elements so in that sense it works with a "list". And the shown template of course matches any `compounddef` which has a corresponding `innerpage`.

Comment: Thanks, update the question with the result and follow up question.